# How can I create an F# async from a C# method with a callback?

Tags: asynchronous, f#

Suppose I have some C# code that takes a callback:

```
void DoSomething(Action<string> callback);
```

Now, I want to use this in F#, but wrap it in an `async`. How would I go about this?

```
// Not real code
let doSomething = async {
  let mutable result = null
  new Action(fun x -> result <- x) |> Tasks.DoSomething
  // Wait for result to be assigned
  return result
}
```

---

For example, suppose `DoSomething` looks like this:

```
module Tasks

  let DoSomething callback = 
    callback "Hello"
    ()
```

Then the output of the following should be `"Hello"`:

```
let wrappedDoSomething = async {
   // Call DoSomething somehow
}

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
  async {
    let! resultOfDoSomething = wrappedDoSomething
    Console.WriteLine resultOfDoSomething
    return ()
  } |> Async.RunSynchronously
  0
```

Comment: Is `async {
    callback()
}` not what you want?

Comment: Well, I need to call `DoSomething` somewhere. Could you post a complete answer?

Comment: Can you be more clear about exactly what you expect the workflow to look like; i.e. what values should be passed into where, and when?  Maybe use more descriptive names than DoSomething and Callback so it's more evident what you're trying to do.

Comment: @DaxFohl Sure, the result of the `async` should be the value passed to the callback, which is a `string`. `doSomething` should have type `Async<String>`.

Comment: I don't understand.  If you have a C# function `DoSomething`, then `DoSomething` is what decides what to pass to the callback.

Comment: Yes it does. And I want the result passed by `DoSomething` to `callback` to be the result of the async.

Comment: That can only be done by modifying your C# function `DoSomething` to accept the result you want to send or a function that produces it.  You can't just magically make it call the callback with something different from what it's coded to do.  You could *wrap* the callback in another callback that ignores the original parameter and injects something else, but I can't tell if that's what you're really asking for.

Comment: Also your example does not follow your question. `DoSomething` in the example does not have a callback. I don't see how it relates.

Comment: @DaxFohl this can very well be done. This callback structure is exactly how Async is implemented inside, you just need to map the callback to Async continuations, and lo: there is an app for that - `Async.FromContinuations`.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Oh, I misunderstood what the OP was trying to do.  I thought he was wanting to pre-specify what string `DoSomething` should call `callback` with. With the updated example and your answer it makes sense now.  Interesting question!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function [Async.FromContinuations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/async.fromcontinuations%5B't%5D-method-%5Bfsharp%5D) is, so to say, the "lowest level" of Async. All other async combinators can be expressed in terms of it.

It is the lowest level in the sense that it directly encodes the very nature of async computations - the knowledge of what to do in the three possible cases: (1) a successful completion of the previous computation step, (2) a crash of the previous computation step, and (3) cancellation from outside. These possible cases are expressed as the three function-typed arguments of the function that you pass to `Async.FromContinuations`. For example:

```
let returnFive = 
    Async.FromContinuations( fun (succ, err, cancl) ->
        succ 5
    )

async {
    let! res = returnFive
    printfn "%A" res  // Prints "5"
} 
|> Async.RunSynchronously
```

Here, my function `fun (succ, err, cancl) -> succ 5` has decided that it has completed successfully, and calls the `succ` continuation to pass its computation result to the next step.

In your case, the function `DoSomething` expresses only one of the three cases - i.e. "what to do on successful completion". Once you're inside the callback, it means that whatever `DoSomething` was doing, has completed successfully. That's when you need to call the `succ` continuation:

```
let doSometingAsync = 
    Async.FromContinuations( fun (succ, err, cancl) -> 
        Tasks.DoSomething( fun res -> succ res ) 
    )
```

Of course, you can avoid a nested lambda-expression `fun res -> succ res` by passing `succ` directly into `DoSomething` as callback. Unfortunately, you'll have to explicitly specify which type of `Action` to use for wrapping it, which negates the advantage:

```
let doSometingAsync = 
    Async.FromContinuations( fun (succ, err, cancl) -> 
        Tasks.DoSomething( System.Action<string> succ ) 
    )
```

---

As an aside, note that this immediately uncovered a hole in the `DoSomething`'s API: it ignores the error case. What happens if `DoSomething` fails to do whatever it was meant to do? There is no way you'd know about it, and the whole async workflow will just hang. Or, even worse: the process will exit immediately (depending on how the crash happens).

If you have any control over `DoSomething`, I suggest you address this issue.

Comment: Well being C#, the error case is probably an `Exception`. A try-with that calls the `err` function could implement this.

Comment: No, it probably isn't an exception. This style of API points towards an asychronous nature of the function. That is, when you call `DoSomethiing`, it starts a background worker thread and immediately returns. If a failure occurs, it would be on the background thread. And since you don't control the entry point of that thread, there is nowhere to catch the exception.

Comment: Yes, good point. More realistic would be a second callback; an error parameter to the callback; or an error-value like `null`. Your answer makes it clear how to handle these though.

Comment: If my answer helped you, would you consider accepting it?

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like:

```
let doSomething callback = async {
    Tasks.DoSomething(callback)
}
```

If your goal is to define the callback in the method you could do something like:

```
let doSomething () = async {
    let callback = new Action<string>(fun result -> printfn "%A" result )
    Tasks.DoSomething(callback)
}
```

If your goal is to have the result of the async method be used in the `DoSomething` callback you could do something like:

```
let doSomething =

         Async.StartWithContinuations(
         async {
            return result
            },
         (fun result -> Tasks.DoSomething(result)),
         (fun _ -> printfn "Deal with exception."),
         (fun _ -> printfn "Deal with cancellation."))
```

Comment: What if I want the result of the `async` to be the result passed to the callback?