# Async<'T> Completion Via Callback

Tags: asynchronous, f#

Noting that the F# `MailboxProcessor` instance provides a `PostAndAsyncReply` member function.

My understanding is that this function provides both:

- An `AsyncReplyChannel<T>` instance which provides a `Reply` member that will be called by the relevant logic within the `MailboxProcessor` itself.
- An `Async<T>` which is actually returned to the caller, and completed once `Reply` is called above.

Behind the [scenes](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/blob/c263094df8594bd5b836467442bd4f40c1e7962d/src/FSharp.Core/mailbox.fs#L450-450), I can see that this is achieved through the use of a `ResultCell` type (as defined [here](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/blob/c5096a2418021054c2b3eb45a79b5f3c0cf3c560/src/FSharp.Core/async.fs#L940)).

Unfortunately, from what I can tell, this is not publicly exposed (likely for good reason).

Avoiding the use of a `MailboxProcessor`, in the absence of `ResultCell` and through sheer ignorance on my part, I *might* be tempted to use the following with signature `'T -> Async<'U>`...

```
let MyPostAndReplyAsync (somethingToPost: 'T): Async<'U> =
    let tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<'U>()

    let reply result =
        tcs.SetResult (result)
           
    // Note that `backgroundOp` returns unit and, at some point in the future,
    // will successfully call `reply`.
    do backgroundOp (somethingToPost, reply)

    tcs.Task |> Async.AwaitTask
```

**Surely there is a more idiomatic approach for a callback to complete an `Async`?**

**...Something that means I don't have to step into the realm of `Task`?**

For the purpose of this, assume that `reply` will always be called successfully and that I'm not concerned about cancellations/exceptions.

---

**Update:**

The following meets the requirements:

```
let MyPostAndReplyAsync (somethingToPost: 'T): Async<'U> =
    Async.FromContinuations (fun (reply, _, _) ->
        backgroundOp (somethingToPost, reply))
```

This was inspired by the following SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50782719/how-can-i-create-an-f-async-from-a-c-sharp-method-with-a-callback).

Answer (score 0):

Either you're overthinking this, or I'm missing something. I think you can simply define `MyPostAndReplyAsync` like this:

```ml
let MyPostAndReplyAsync backgroundOp (somethingToPost: 'T): Async<'U> =
    let reply result =
        async { return result }
    backgroundOp somethingToPost reply
```

Test case:

```ml
let backgroundOp somethingToPost reply =
    reply $"Replying to {somethingToPost}"

MyPostAndReplyAsync backgroundOp "Hello"
    |> Async.RunSynchronously   // "Replying to Hello"
    |> printfn "%s"
```

Comment: Just to set the context... I was having a go at (badly) implementing a `MailboxProcessor`, but with a priority queue. The call to `backgroundOp` effectively places a message in the relevant queue which will ultimately lead to the callback being called and the `Async` value completing. For my purposes, I need something that works exactly like `AsyncReplyChannel`, but outside of the vanilla `MailboxProcessor`. What is frustrating, is that the "bits" that make `AsyncReplyChannel` work, are specific to `MailboxProcessor`.